# How can the union of X and Y be equal to the intersection of Y and Z (X u Y = Y n Z)?

Tags: set, formal-languages

On which conditions can the equation X u Y = Y n Z be true?

I need to prove this equation step by step, but I do not know where to start.

Comment: When X = Y = Z (ie, all 3 sets are equal), then X union Y = Y and Y intersection Z = Y. Thus, it is one possible condition.

Comment: Another potential condition: if X is a subset of Y and Y = Z, then again X union Y = Y and Y intersection Z = Y.

Comment: X u Y = Y n Z. Apply `n (Y n Z)` to both sides of the equation. (X u Y) n (Y n Z) = (Y n Z) n (Y n Z). This is simplified as (X n Y n Z) u (Y n Y n Z) = Y n Z. Which is same as: (X n Y n Z) u (Y n Z) = (Y n Z). This means that X n Y n Z must be a subset of Y n Z. This is the condition for the equation to be true.

Comment: How is this a programming matter? We learned this in math class.

Comment: I just started a class called "Introduction to formal languages" so I thought that would be adequate @matt

Answer (score 0):

X union Y = Y intersect Z if and only if X is a (possibly improper) subset of Y and Y is a (possibly improper) subset of Z.

To prove this, we need to show the implication in both directions.

If X is a (possibly improper) subset of Y and Y is a (possibly improper) subset of Z, is it true that X union Y = Y intersect Z? Because X is a subset of Y, X union Y = Y. Because Y is a subset of Z, Y intersect Z = Y. Thus, X union Y = Y = Y intersect Z, as required.

If X union Y = Y intersect Z, is it true that both X is a subset of Y and Y is a subset of Z? Suppose X were not a subset of Y. That means there is some x in X not in Y. So, X union Y must contain x. But Y intersect Z cannot contain anything not in Y, such as x; therefore, X union Y cannot equal Y intersect Z - a contradiction. Suppose instead Y were not a subset of Z. Then Y would contain some element y not in Z. But then Y intersect Z does not contain y, whereas X union Y must. So, X union Y cannot equal Y intersect Z, a contradiction.

This completes the proof that X union Y = Y intersect Z iff X is a (possibly improper) subset of Y and Y is a (possibly improper) subset of Z.

Note: X is a proper subset of Y if X is a subset of Y but X is not equal to Y. If X equals Y, it is an "improper" subset.